# No module Flask.ext.paginate using python

Tags: flask

I'm trying to test the following code on Github  https://github.com/rohitsakala/CassandraRestfulAPI by following the instructions, unfortunately the execution does not work, and I have the following errors : 
[image]

[image]

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is what you would see if the version of Python that you're using to run your server doesn't have `flask_paginate` installed. Try running `pip install -U flask_paginate`.

Comment: Thank you, and for module "libvirt", how to install it ?

Comment: Try `pip install -U libvirt-python`. I got the name of the package from [the pypi website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libvirt-python).

Comment: it does not work, I have : 

 Package libvirt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libvirt.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libvirt' found
    Package libvirt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libvirt.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libvirt' found

Comment: It's work after : sudo apt-get install python-tox pkg-config libvirt-dev python-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev